# How to set Home and Path directories in C?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am programming a small unix shell written in c. I want it to do only some basic commands for now. e.g. ls, pwd, ch

My problem is how do I set the Home directory and Path directory? I want to read the configuration from a text file so it can be easily changed whenever.

I am going to be using execv() to call unix functions such as ls. For example PATH
should determine the directories my shell should use to search for executable programs
when the user types a command

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you want to set? What do **you** mean by "Home directory"? What do **you** mean by "Path directory"? The former has a common meaning, is set in the configuration file `/etc/passwd`, and read by routines like `getpwnam()`. The latter has no common meaning that I am aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all simply environment variables that you manipulate e. g. through `setenv(3)` (run `man 3 setenv` for details). The variables are `HOME` and `PATH`. See also `man 7 environ`.

Note that setting/changing an environment variable only influences the *current* process and all processes forked from it *after* the setting/changing (unlike in Windows, AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function `setenv`. See `man 3 setenv` for information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unix already offers you an environmental variable that contains all the paths where system executables are stored.  Retrieve the variable in your code with `getenv("PATH");` Each path is separated with a ':' so all you need to do is tokenize and begin searching those paths for the executable your command wants to run.  In this function you should also be able to search any path of your choosing for an executable.

You can decide what directory you want to start in ("home directory" as you say) by manipulating the current working directory before the shell prompts with `chdir()`.  You can also use that unix function for implementing a `cd` command that can be used throughout the run time of the shell.